# Future.traverse seems to work sequentially and not in parallel. Is this true?

Tags: scala

My question is simple, about Future.traverse method.
So I have a list of String-s. Each string is an URL to a web page. Then I have a class which can take an URL, load the web page and parse some data. All this is wrapped into Future{} so the result is processed asynchronously.

The class is simplified looking like this:

```
class RatingRetriever(context:ExecutionContext) {
  def resolveFilmToRating(url:String):Future[Option[Double]]={
    Future{
      //here it creates Selenium web driver, loads the url and parses it.
    }(context)
  }
}
```

Then in the other object I have this:

```
    implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
    .......
    val links:List[String] = films.map(film => film.asInstanceOf[WebElement].getAttribute("href"))
    val ratings: Future[List[Option[Double]]] = Future.traverse(links)(link => new RatingRetriever(executionContext).resolveFilmToRating(link))
```

When it works I can definitely see it goes through collection sequentially. If I change the execution context from fixed size pool to single thread pool the behavior is the same.
So I really wonder how can I make the Future.traverse work in parallel. Can you advise?

Comment: `Future.traverse` does work in parallel. If you execution context has two fixed threads, it takes the first two links to load and parse, than the next two and so on.

Comment: @PeterNeyens : Probably. If that was so, I would not post this question :) I have debugged it quite a lot.
So for each link a Selenium web driver instance is created which starts the Firefox browser and loads the page. If it took 2 links I would see 2 browsers, but I only see a single one opened, page loaded, then browser closed, then next one is opened, etc. If I change thread pool size to let's say 4 (I have 4 cores in my processor) then nothing changes.
So probably the thing is not with Future.traversal, but with something else, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Then please provide some code that compiles that can show the behavior you are describing.

Comment: @m-z if I share the code in Github that would be ok?

Comment: Code in GitHub: https://github.com/AlexanderArendar/IMDBAverage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at traverse's sources:

```
in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) => //we sequentially traverse Collection
  val fb = fn(a)                        //Your function comes here
  for (r <- fr; b <- fb) yield (r += b) //Just add elem to builder
}.map(_.result())                       //Getting the collection from builder
```

So how much parallel you code is depends on your function fn, take a look at two examples:

1) This code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
object FutureTraverse extends App{
  def log(s: String) = println(s"${Thread.currentThread.getName}: $s")

  def withDelay(i: Int) = Future{
    log(s"withDelay($i)")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    i
  }

  val seq = 0 to 10

  Future {
    for(i <- 0 to 5){
      log(".")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }

  val resultSeq = Future.traverse(seq)(withDelay(_))

  Thread.sleep(6000)
}
```

Has such an output:

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3: withDelay(0)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(1)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(2)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3: withDelay(3)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(4)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(5)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3: withDelay(6)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(7)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(8)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3: withDelay(9)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(10)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: .
```

2) Just change the withDelay function:

```
  def withDelay(i: Int) = {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    Future {
      log(s"withDelay($i)")
      i
    }
  }
```

and you'll get a sequential output:

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: withDelay(0)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(1)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(2)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(3)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: .
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(4)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(5)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(6)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: withDelay(7)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(8)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(9)
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: withDelay(10)
```

So Future.traverse doesn't have to be a parallel one, it just submits tasks, it can do this sequentially, whole parallel thing is in your submitted function.

Comment: thanks. I understand your explanation and example but do not completely understand why in example 2) you have not just swap log() and Trhead.sleep() lines but moved Thread.sleep() out of the Future{} wrapper?

Comment: Future submits a task for concurrent execution. More things inside Future block - more parrallel your code will be, because things outside Future block are executed sequentially - thats the main thing I wanted to tell, and Thread.sleep symbolizes time consuming operation

Answer (score 10):

Scala's `Future.traverse` **does** work in parallel. How much is performed in parallel is determined by the `ExecutionContext`! Underneath, the Scala `Future` just schedules a task on a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`. If a thread is available, the task is executed directly. Otherwise, it will be scheduled to run when one becomes available.

It's a bit difficult to see where in the `Future.traverse` implementation, the parallelism comes from

```
def traverse(in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B]) =
  in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
    val fb = fn(a)
    for (r <- fr; b <- fb) yield (r += b)
  }.map(_.result())
```

But the trick here is defining `fb` *before* the for-comprehension!
By executing the `fn` function and therefore creating a `Future` instance, this Future is scheduled to run right away.
The for-comprehension waits for the future to complete and add the result to the accumulator.

Its parallelism can easily be made visible by choosing a different `ExecutionContext`

```
val tp1 = java.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(tp1)
Future.traverse((1 to 5)) { n => Future { sleep; println(n); n }}
1
2
3
4
5
```

When increasing the number of threads, the functions will run in parallel

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.Future
def sleep = Thread.sleep(100 + Random.nextInt(1000))

val tp5 = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(tp5)
Future.traverse((1 to 5)) { n => Future { sleep; println(n); n }}
3
2
4
5
1
```

Comment: I think what's happening here is not that the function you pass to `traverse` is running concurrently, but rather the function you pass to `Future`. Traverse is still sequential, but of course you're free to start any kind of async work within your function, and that work can be run concurrently. The `val fb = fn(a)` line in the source of `traverse` is run for each item in the collection, in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

@nikiforo clear, thanks. Regarding my particular problem it was that somehow selenium web-driver wants each instance to be instantiated in a separate thread if I want few browsers to work simultaneously. So I needed to use custom Thread implementation:

```
class FireFoxThread(r:Runnable) extends Thread(r:Runnable){
  val driver = new FirefoxDriver

  override def interrupt()={
    driver.quit
    super.interrupt
  }
}
```

And then instantiate it from ThreadFactory:

```
val executorService:ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3, new ThreadFactory {
      override def newThread(r: Runnable): Thread = new FireFoxThread(r)
})
```

That way I was able to process my URLs in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`Future.traverse` does work sequentially. It takes each of the items in the `TraversableOnce` you pass as an argument (`links` in this case), and creates a future using your mapping function. However, it only creates this future when the previous future has finished executing, which enforces the sequential behaviour you've seen.

You can see this clearly with a simple code example:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def sleep = Thread.sleep(100 + Random.nextInt(5000))

Future.traverse((1 to 100)){n => sleep; println(n); Future.successful(n)}
```

This prints the numbers from 1 to 100 in series, and never out-of-order. If the futures were executed in parallel, the random sleep would ensure some items complete earlier than those dispatched before them, but this doesn't happen.

Looking at the source of `Future.traverse`, we can see why this is the case:

```
def traverse(in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B]) =
  in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
    val fb = fn(a)
    for (r <- fr; b <- fb) yield (r += b)
  }.map(_.result())
```

The `for (r <- fr; b <- fb)` part is a for comprehension that is calling flatMap on the future you provide. Once the future your callback creates (`fb`) has finished executing, it's added to the result list. This doesn't happen until the previous future (`fr`) has finished and can flatMap to its result.

If you want to submit a set of futures in parallel, you can use `Future.sequential`:

```
val retriver = new RatingRetriever(executionContext)
Future.sequence(links.map(link => retriver.resolveFilmToRating(link))
```

In this case, you're creating the futures in the `links.map` call and so they all start executing immediately. `Future.sequence` does the relatively simple work of transforming the list of futures into a list of their results.

Comment: I am not able to see `Future.sequential` in 2.11.9 or 2.12.3 source code of the `Future` companion object... Could you clarify?
I can see `Future.sequence`.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderArendar! I've edited the answer to specify Future.sequence.

Comment: @mcobrien Sorry to say you're wrong. `Future.traverse` _is_ parallel. Have a look at my answer below. What you did wrong was doing the sleep outside of the Future. This effects the execution the `foldLeft` and since the Future completes immediately you would see everything sequencial. By moving the sleep function into the Future, you'll see results popping up randomly.